# What loop should I use and how?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, swap

The program is, the user will input the start value, end value and the interval. The output should be, the start_value will be added to the interval until it reach to the end value. I want to display some message if the output is greater than the end value. Example:

```
Enter start value:5
 Enter end value: 30
 Enter interval value: 5
 Output: 5 10 15 20 25 30 // correct output
 2nd try
 Enter start value:5
 Enter end value: 30
 Enter interval value: 6
 Output: 5 11 17 23 29 35 // wrong output
```

**My code:**

```
while(start_value <= end_value)
{
    start_value = start_value + interval_value;             
    printf("%d ",start_value);                          
}
```

Comment: "when the start_value is greater than end_value it will produce infinite loop" - nonsense.

Comment: *when the start_value is greater than end_value* - No it won't. You probably have some integer overflow somewhere.

Comment: The code shown does not behave as you describe.  Please update your question with a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if your problem is that 35 is shown in the second output, even though 35 > 30, it is because you don't increment the value by the interval until after you check the number.  your value when checked by the while condition is 29, then you are adding 6 in your example, bringing it to 35.  I would make the condition in the while loop `while((start_value+interval_value) <= end_value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print first, *then* increment.

```
while(start_value <= end_value)
{
    printf("%d ",start_value);                          
    start_value = start_value + interval_value;             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a deciding if-condition. And, move your printf() statement before performing the increment.

if start_value > end_value, then swap them;
else, continue the same loop.

For ease, introduce a temp variable to swap the values.

```
if(start_value > end_value){
temp = start_value;
start_value = end_value;
end_value = temp;
}

while(start_value <= end_value)
{
   printf("%d ",start_value);
   start_value = start_value + interval_value;

}
```

Comment: @mvidelgauz - Didn't get what you said! Please elaborate.

Comment: But obviously it does not address the *real* problem the OP indirectly discribing..

Comment: You asked "Am I Helpful", I am saying "yes you are" (in addition to upvoting your answer :-) )

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I don't find how OP's problem is not solved, once he decides to swap or not before entering the loop as I've shown.

Comment: @mvidelgauz - Thanks, :). Though it seems I'm helpful, but, I'm confused too as I couldn't understand your words.

Comment: Because the *"when the start_value is greater than end_value"* part doesn't make sense unless there some overflow is happening. And your solution won't help.

Comment: @EugeneSh. and _real_ problem is ... ?

Comment: I couldn't get your point, maybe you'd like to write an answer for OP covering your case? I could think only this case for the question. @EugeneSh.

Comment: That's probably my problem, not yours, i'll try to express my mind better next time ))

Comment: I agree with @EugeneSh. that this may or may not solve the actual problem. Why necesarily to swap? May be start > end indicates that empty loop should take place (instead of endless). OP didn't provide Software Requirements Document...

Comment: My point is that there is no way in the world the while loop is entered and looping infinitely if start is greater than end value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. as long as `<` or `<=` is used as condition, like it is now. But for some reason I thought there was `!=`, probably I misread that...

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you know your start and stopping points (input variables count as knowing), For loops are industry standard.

If you are concerned about the condition of a starting value being greater than the ending value, you should include validation code before entering the loop.  I'd recommend having a function that takes in the input variables and checks, and then either allowing the program to continue or prompting the user for valid input.

Edit: also you aren't getting an infinite loop with your code, as the number would increase until it hit the maximum integer (approx 2 billion), wrap around to the minimum integer (approx negative 2 billion) and keep going until the end value is reached.  However, you aren't clearing your buffer with `printf("\n");` which is likely where your problem lies.  Furthermore, if the condition isn't true as described in the while loop's conditions you probably just aren't entering it when the starting value is greater.

Comment: "... For loops are industry standard. Massive oversimplification.

Comment: @Olaf True, but in something like the original post, it is typically standard.

Comment: Not really. A lot of coding style guides forbid assignments in conditions. How would you write it as a `for` loop? There is not update expression at the end, but the start of the block.

Comment: @Olaf honestly if I were OP I would restructure the loop.  Although it is possible to make a for loop where you increment at the beginning at the block.

Comment: Yes, and you can put a screw into a wall with a hammer. If your only tool is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail. Write the most understandable code first, unless this will screw the program.

Answer (score 0):

logically when the condition become false, the loop terminating. it is better you put all of your code to see what is going on with variables, but
you can use proper `if` and `break` statement inside loop to cut execution of the loop anytime.